# Routing problems in CakePHP 4.0.3 'A route matching X could not be found'

Tags: cakephp-4.x

I'm making a web app that has a backend REST API written in CakePHP 4.0.3 and a frontend consumer written in Vue.js 2.6.11 using axios 0.19.2 to make requests.

The problem is that I can't call the DELETE method on any of my endpoints and I can't tell whether the problem is in the frontend or backend code.

In the server log it says:

```
2020-02-14 10:55:54 Error: [Cake\Routing\Exception\MissingRouteException] A route matching "/meal-plans/14042e24-fa12-49d3-9bbe-91e57847a1c7" could not be found. in /var/www/html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/RouteCollection.php on line 211
Exception Attributes: array (
  'url' => '/meal-plans/14042e24-fa12-49d3-9bbe-91e57847a1c7',
)
Stack Trace:
- /var/www/html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Router.php:227
- /var/www/html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/RoutingMiddleware.php:140
- /var/www/html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73
- /var/www/html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:58
- /var/www/html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Server.php:90
- /var/www/html/webroot/index.php:40

Request URL: /meal-plans/14042e24-fa12-49d3-9bbe-91e57847a1c7
Referer URL: http://localhost:8080/
Client IP: 172.19.0.1
```

Realising it's just a routing issue, I type `bin/cake routes` into the terminal:

```
+------------------+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Route name       | URI template    | Defaults                                                                           |
+------------------+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| mealplans:index  | /meal-plans     | {"_method":"GET","action":"index","controller":"MealPlans","plugin":null}          |
| mealplans:add    | /meal-plans     | {"_method":"POST","action":"add","controller":"MealPlans","plugin":null}           |
| mealplans:view   | /meal-plans/:id | {"_method":"GET","action":"view","controller":"MealPlans","plugin":null}           |
| mealplans:edit   | /meal-plans/:id | {"_method":["PUT","PATCH"],"action":"edit","controller":"MealPlans","plugin":null} |
| mealplans:delete | /meal-plans/:id | {"_method":"DELETE","action":"delete","controller":"MealPlans","plugin":null}      |
| meals:index      | /meals          | {"_method":"GET","action":"index","controller":"Meals","plugin":null}              |
| meals:add        | /meals          | {"_method":"POST","action":"add","controller":"Meals","plugin":null}               |
| meals:view       | /meals/:id      | {"_method":"GET","action":"view","controller":"Meals","plugin":null}               |
| meals:edit       | /meals/:id      | {"_method":["PUT","PATCH"],"action":"edit","controller":"Meals","plugin":null}     |
| meals:delete     | /meals/:id      | {"_method":"DELETE","action":"delete","controller":"Meals","plugin":null}          |
+------------------+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But as you can see, it says the routes are loaded.

I wrote a test to see if it could give me any clues. The test should've failed

```php
class MealPlansControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    use IntegrationTestTrait;

    public $fixtures = [
        'app.MealPlans',
        'app.Meals'
    ];

    public function testDelete()
    {
        $this->assertCountRecords(1);

        $this->delete('/meal-plans/14042e24-fa12-49d3-9bbe-91e57847a1c7');
        $this->assertResponseCode(204);

        $this->assertCountRecords(0);
    }

    public function testDeleteInvalid()
    {
        $this->assertCountRecords(1);

        $this->delete('/meal-plans/14042f24-fa12-49d3-9bbe-91e57847a1c7');
        $this->assertResponseCode(404);

        $this->assertCountRecords(1);
    }

    private function assertCountRecords($expected)
    {
        $this->get('/meal-plans');
        $this->assertResponseCode(200);

        $body = json_decode((string) $this->_response->getBody(), true);
        $this->assertArrayHasKey('mealPlans', $body);
        $this->assertEquals($expected, count($body['mealPlans']));
    }

}
```

But both tests passed so it wasn't really helpful at all.

So now I'm stuck. I have no clue whats going on. It's probably something simple but I can't see it.

These are the offending routes:

```php
/** @var RouteBuilder $routes */
$routes->setRouteClass(DashedRoute::class);
$routes->scope('/', function (RouteBuilder &$builder) {
    $builder->setExtensions(['json']);
    $builder->resources('MealPlans');
    $builder->resources('Meals');
});
```

This is the controller I'm trying to use:

```php
/**
 * Class MealPlansController
 * @package App\Controller
 *
 * @property MealPlansTable $MealPlans
 */
class MealPlansController extends AppController
{
    public $modelClass = 'MealPlans';

    public function delete($id)
    {
        try {
            $mealPlan = $this->MealPlans->get($id);
        } catch (RecordNotFoundException $e) {
            $this->response = $this->response->withStatus(404, __d('meal_plans', 'delete_404'));
            return $this->render();
        }
        if ($this->MealPlans->delete($mealPlan)) {
            $this->response = $this->response->withStatus(204, __d('meal_plans', 'delete_200'));
        } else {
            $this->response = $this->response->withStatus(500, __d('meal_plans', 'delete_500'));
        }
        return $this->render();
    }
}
```

The frontend call looks like this:

```js
deleteMealPlan (mealPlan) {
    axios.delete('http://localhost:11000/meal-plans/' + mealPlan.id)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.statusText);
            this.$store.dispatch('planner/syncMealPlans').then(() => this.$forceUpdate());
        });
}
```

And the endpoint being called looks like `http://localhost:11000/meal-plans/14042e24-fa12-49d3-9bbe-91e57847a1c7`

I can GET the above endpoint just fine, I haven't tested PUT or PATCH yet.

The only other relevant piece of code is my middleware setup:

```php
$middlewareQueue
    ->add(new ErrorHandlerMiddleware(Configure::read('Error')))
    ->add(new AssetMiddleware([
        'cacheTime' => Configure::read('Asset.cacheTime'),
    ]))
    ->add(new RoutingMiddleware($this))
    ->add(new BodyParserMiddleware(['json' => true]))
    ->add(function (ServerRequest $request, Response $response, $next) {
        // Allow CORS
        return $next($request, $response)
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

This was a problem with my middleware.

I was aware that web browsers send a pre-flight request and by enabling the CORS headers, I thought I had covered myself.

**However**

I was allowing all requests to go through regardless of the request method. This would let OPTIONS requests to go through to the router.

When the router tried to parse the request and get the correct route, it would fail to find any routes with OPTIONS defined in the `_method` option and producing the error.

And that explains why my tests were passing. Since an OPTIONS request was never made, the error never came up.

So the solution is to return early if the request is an OPTIONS request

```php
function (ServerRequest $request, Response $response, $next) {
    if ($request->getMethod() === 'OPTIONS') {
        return $response
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    } else {
        $response = $next($request, $response)
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

        return $response;
    }
}
```